# UIButton Title not updating all the time

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am programmatically changing the title of a `UIButton` to display count of items in a `NSMutableArray`.

Sometimes, the title does not update as I add items to the array. When I do the `NSLog` of what the title should be, it is correct but the button title does not update all the time.

Can anyone spot a problem with my code?

```
- (void) refreshAfterBlueToothScan
{
    /*************************************Refresh Displayed Total********************/

    //[_manualBCtemporaryCartArray26 removeAllObjects];

    //_manualBCtemporaryCartArray26 =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [localTempArray removeAllObjects];

    if (!localTempArray)

    {
        localTempArray =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }



    // Get the DBAccess object;
    DBAccess *dbAccess1 = [[DBAccess alloc] init];

    // Get the products array from the database

    //Get the latest NSMutableArray
    localTempArray = [dbAccess1 getProductsFromTmpSales];

    // Close the database because we are finished with it
    [dbAccess1 closeDatabase];



    //Count How many products in array

    int iNumberofArrayProducts;

    iNumberofArrayProducts = [localTempArray count];

    NSString* productCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", iNumberofArrayProducts];

    NSLog(@"The NUMBER OF TmpTable PRODUCTS is %@",productCount);


    //Sum the selling price of the records in the _manualBCtemporaryCartArray26

    amountSum = [localTempArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.lTotalSellingPrice"];

    NSLog(@"The total TmpTable SELLING PRICE is %@",amountSum);



    NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2]; // Set this if you need 2 digits
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2]; // Set this if you need 2 digits
    NSString * newString =  [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[amountSum floatValue]]];

    NSLog(@"FORMATTED MONTHLY SALES IS,R%@",newString);

    //This is a hack that replaces the comma with a dot. I want to display the Price as      R2 000.10
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/:,"];
    newString=[[newString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @"."];


    NSString *item = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R%@ (%i)",newString, iNumberofArrayProducts];


    /**********Play audio to warn user that item was added to cart*******/


    // ivar
    SystemSoundID mBeep;

    // Create the sound ID
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource:@"scanBarCode" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)url, &mBeep);

    // Play the sound
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mBeep);

    // Dispose of the sound
    //AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(mBeep);

    /**********END - Play audio to warn user that item was added to cart*******/


    //When user scans the barcode, we want to display the product that was just scanned. This allows user to see what product they just scanned as it is automatically loaded on the shopping cart. Put IF Statement so this code only executes after the scanning barcode.

    [self.searchDisplayController setActive: YES animated: YES];
    //self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = NO;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",fklInventoryID];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];

     NSLog(@"BUTTON ITEM IS,%@",item);
    [manualTotalPriceBtn setTitle: item forState: UIControlStateNormal];


    /*************************************END - Refresh Displayed Total********************/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[manualTotalPriceBtn setAttributedTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[manualTotalPriceBtn setTitle:item forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If you are using a xib file the IB will set your value for the attributedTitle instead of the title.

Comment: Tried it and it's not working. The UIButton is in view B. When I get to View B from View A the first time everything works 100%. However, if I segue from View B to View A and then segue back to View B, the problem occurs.

Comment: I'm thinking that after you tap the button it changes it's state to selected so why don't you try forState:UIControlStateSelected.

@BDR

Comment: I actually don't tap the button. I have bluetooth scanner that scans barcode and the decoded barcode is populated into an array. I then count items in array and update UIButton title with number of items in array. I actually did NSLog(@" The button's title is %@.", self.manualTotalPriceBtn.currentTitle); It shows correctly but still button title is not updating.

Comment: I have been debugging the code to try and find the issue. What is consistent is that when I scan barcode using socketmobile bluetooth scanner, sometimes _parentModalViewController = (UIViewController *) nil. Whenever this happens, the title of the UIButton does not update. When _parentModalViewController = (UITabBarController *) 0x1c5cb6d8, the App works all the time. Somehow I think the scanning causes referencing to be lost?

Comment: Yes is it your _parentViewController a strong reference? Are you using ARC? try to declare property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *parentModalViewController;

Answer (score 0):

try changing button type from system to custom.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you update the button on the mainthread. If your method is called from a callback of whatever bluetooth scanner module you are using, it might be happening on a backround thread. This will cause button to sometimes update, sometimes it will not, or later.

If not, check the superview property of the button to not be nil. Maybe somewhere in your code you create a bew button, add it to the superview but forgot update your property to point to it (or some other scenario where you update a button that is not inserted in the view).